# Override default php function

Tags: php, function, overriding

I have script wherein `basename()` is used 100-1000s of time, I was just thinking if we can override the function rather than changing the function name to something else in all scripts.

The problem with `basename()` is that it doesnt works well with names of files in foreign languages. I found one on php site http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php but it needs `PECL` any other alternative?

Comment: On a related note, if it doesn't work well, submit a bug report at http://bugs.php.net/

Comment: @Artefacto, Sometimes they can't just change it due to backwards compat issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use namespaces to override existing function names:

```
namespace blarg;
function basename() {
  return 'whatever';
}
$base = basename();
```

I.e., any call to basename() within the blarg namespace will use your new version of the function.

Comment: Remember that namespaces are only supported in PHP 5.3 and later.

Comment: Attempting to otherwise override a function will result in a 'function already exists' error.  Lacking 5.3: create a function `xbasename()` that encapsulates the true basename function along with another method for handling non-ansi characters.  Then, CTRL-A & CTRL-H... I'm sure everyone knows the rest.

Comment: sometimes override implementation needs to call original function. In this example is there a way to call the original basename from the new basename ?

Comment: Prefix the function name with a backslash to indicate that you want the one in the root namespace: \basename();

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I am now trying to use this function in other php files. I first tried 'require_once('overridebasename.php'); use blarg.basename; 'whihc is not working by the way. But anyway this quite a pain if I want to override several functions. Is there a way to inject all overidden function after require_once ? NB: starting with every file with 'namespace blarg; require_once 'overridebasename.php'; do the trick but affect the file's namespace.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be [runkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-rename.php). But that's as unlikely to be enabled on most servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the locale before calling basename:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
```

[setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)