# PHP if function is called, how to override it with another function

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Override default php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927995/override-default-php-function)

Is there a way to detect that a function is being called and override with a separate function?  I'm not sure function_exists does that.

Comment: I think your asking the wrong question. Why do you need to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Override default php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927995/override-default-php-function)

> You can use namespaces to override
>   existing function names:
>
> ```
> namespace blarg;
> function basename() {
>     return 'whatever';
> }
> $base = basename();
> ```
>
> I.e., any call to basename() within
>   the blarg namespace will use your new
>   version of the function.

Comment: This only works for php 5.3.0 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

The [override_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) function may be what you need, but it seems ugly.

However, using namespaces or inheritance are probably better options.

Comment: I think this requires PECL or something

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to? There is probably a better solution to the original problem.

Also, do you want to override a built in PHP function, or one that you have written yourself. Is it a method on an object, or a static function?