# Make getimagesize() referenced cached values

Tags: php, zen-cart, php-internals, getimagesize

I am tweaking a zen-cart website to be more cpu efficient. After profiling it, I see that the getimagesize function is accounting for nearly 50% of page load time. The images are locally stored. One option is to go through zen-cart's source code and replace this function with something custom to reference a cached value since images are rarely ever changed. However, since php is open source, perhaps another option is available: Is there any way to modify this function to make it just read a value from a cache which I can set whenever I upload an image to the server? Maybe by adding an optional parameter to the function that makes it read from cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting idea, but this would require recompiling PHP. While not impossible, it's probably not a good idea from a maintenance point of view: You would have to re-integrate your patch on every PHP update.

However, you *might*  be able to override `getimagesize()`: There seem to be PHP modules and libraries that can add this capability to PHP.

I have no experience with any of them, but here are some suggestions on how to do it:

- [PHP - override existing function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725194/php-override-existing-function)
- [Override default php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927995/override-default-php-function) (the namespaces idea is clever, but probably won't work in your case)